# How could I use MVVM and EF Core together in my (small) WPF App?

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, mvvm, entity-framework-core

I googled a lot and a lot and I still don't understand things clearly and I don't know how to solve my problems.
I would like to use **WPF**, **MVVM** and I would like to create an **SQLite** database for the project. My app doesn't need a huge database in a server, a simply db file is enough in the same directory where .exe is.

- **Models** folder for modell classes for database. In this class, there are just properties and attributes such as [Key], [Required]....
- **Repositories** folder for repository classes for CRUD operations for each table.
- **Views** folder for XAML.
- **ViewModels** folder for viewmodels for each pages (I have 6 pages). View classes inherits from BindableBase (Prism for WPF).

My main problem is where should I put models of MVVM? **What** should be the models for that?

Comment: You can adopt a _canonical data model_ such that the same model can be used for _any_ tier/technology whether it be data; comms (WCF); or presentation; without having multiple versions of say `Customer` and having to deal with tedius; expensive; and error-prone data transformation as data moves about.  A model is a model is a model; owned by none and as such is agnostic

Comment: It looks like you are going to use Entity with a model setup between the c# classes and the SQLite database.  Then build interfaces to the c# classes for your WPF Views.

Comment: So if I have for example a **Costs** model class that represents a table, I should also have a **ICosts** interface?